# Missing 'street' and 'city' fields in Mongoose user document's 'address' sub-document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Why are the street and city fields not present in the address sub-document of a new user document created using Mongoose, despite being included in the addressSchema and provided when creating the document?

Here is my addressSchema:

```js
const addressSchema = new Schema({
  address: {
    street: String,
    city: String
  }
});
```

here is my userSchema:

```js
const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  email: String,
  createdAt: Date,
  updatedAt: Date,
  bestFriend: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
  hobbies: [String],
  address: addressSchema,
})
```

And here is how I'm creating the new user document:

```js
const user = await User.create({
  name: 'amal',
  age: 25,
  hobbies: ['weight lifting', 'Bowling'],
  address: {
    street: 'ernakulam',
    city: 'kochi'
  }
});
```

However, when I log the resulting document, it only contains an _id field for the address sub-document, and the street and city fields are not present.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure that the street and city fields are included in the address sub-document when creating a new user document?

Comment: Please show the code where you create the User model/schema.

Comment: Please review the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) as well-formatted questions are more likely to be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  email: String,
  createdAt: Date,
  updatedAt: Date,
  bestFriend: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
  hobbies: [String],
  address: addressSchema,
})
```

=> The address field should be the type of `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`,

The address schema should be

```js
const AddressSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  street: String,
  city: String
})
```

In that way whenever you wanna get the address of a user you can populate the address field with `.populate('address')`

Answer (score 0):

Your address schema should be like this:

```js
const addressSchema = new Schema({
  street: String,
  city: String
});
```

Otherwise the street and city properties would be at `user.address.address.street` and `user.address.address.city`.